# Flutter read all files from asset folder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have an assets folder in which I have a tab folder and then a list of folders and each folder contains some files:

[image]

I want to read the names of all the files and folders that are in my assets folder. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have tried using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) library but it don't work. It throughs exceptions. I looked up in AssetManifest.json as I read somewhere that this file contains information about every asset but it seems like it only contains information that we enter in pubspec.yaml. I don't want to add all file paths to pubspec.yaml. I added `assets: - assets/` to get all files available for use in my code. Now I need each file path in a list or map without hard coding them in my code, so that I can iterate through them and show them in a ListView. Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I met same matter as you

Comment: I have to hard code the strings. but I haven't tried @Spatz answer. You can try that.

Comment: I want to list all images of /assets/images/wallpapers/ directory and store them in a List type variable to use further, how can i do?

Comment: Future myGetAssetImages() async {
    final manifestJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
    List<String> images = json.decode(manifestJson).keys.where((String key)=>key.startsWith('assets/images/wallpapers')).toList();
    return images;
  } -- From @Spatz answer. It has worked for me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even if you specified only asset folders in `pubspec.yaml`, the flutter compiler lists all files from these folders in `AssetManifest.json` file. All we have to do is read this file:

```dart
final manifestJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
final images = json.decode(manifestJson).keys.where((String key) => key.startsWith('assets/images'));
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems like this file contains information that we enter in pubspec.yaml. So, I don't want to enter all asset names in the manifest.

Comment: @Taha Malik You have to place only folder names (with trailing slash) in pubspec.yaml, not an asset file names.

Comment: can use by this way without context
```final manifestJson = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json')```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is, open your pubspec.yaml and in the assets line, change it as given below - just add the entire folder.

```
assets:
  - assets/
```

This will add all the folders and files in the asset folders.

Comment: I was doing :
`assets:
         - assets/`
it get all the files without * as well. This only allows an asset to be used in your app. Still we have to know each file and directory name and hard code them into our code. What I want is I want an iterative solution i.e. i don't know how many files or folders are there in assets folder just get all file paths and show all files in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I've got same issue,

As of sep 2021, there is still no way to get all the assets without manually listing it in `pubspec.yaml` before calling

```
final manifestJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
```

However there is workaround, if you are using Android Studio/IntelliJ
You can install
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13629-flutter-assets-ref-generator

Then you can use it to list all your assets files into `pubspec.yaml` with one click of button.

It solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Flutter Official, they now provide the common way to insert all the files in the directories.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/sub_directory/
```

ref : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

*Spatz*'s answer is correct, however you don't always have `context` available.

In those cases, you can use `rootBundle`:

```
final manifestJson = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
final images = json.decode(manifestJson).keys.where((String key) => key.startsWith('assets/images'));
```